# How to call windows phone c# code from javascript and viceversa?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8, bridge

I am new to windows phone development. I was looking for some way to bridge my site's javascript code with windows phone c# code and vice-versa. Basically I am working to launch my web-app as windows phone.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used window.external.notify for now for js to c# and ScriptNotify for c# to js. But any other alternate for js to c# would still be appreciated

Comment: did you get anything alternative. It will be great if you share your findings. I am also looking for something like you want. here is my question for same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262029/communication-between-html-in-webbrowser-and-windows-phone-app

Comment: Nope. I am still using the method I answered here. And I am pretty satisfied with it.