# Communication between HTML in WebBrowser and windows phone app

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

I have some static html files downloaded into Isolated store. I am trying to open those files using Web Browser control inside windows phone app. Now every HTML file will communicate with back-end code through javascript, and `window.external.notify()` is not able to apply for all html pages.

So my question is,

Is there any API like (in iOS) [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) and [GAJavaScript](https://github.com/newyankeecodeshop/GAJavaScript) or like (android) `Javascript Interface` available for windows phone 8 which will communicate with HTML in WebBrowser and windows phone app. Will **[WinJS](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/winjs)** supports the same for Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Could you please be more precise in what you actually need? Do you want to intercept all XHR requests made by JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

For receiving data from HTML to phone:

You need to add event handler for ScriptNotify event of WebBrowser. After that, whenever you call window.external.Notify(args) inside html page, ScriptNotify will fire and you'll get the args in Value property of NotifyEventArgs parameter.

in javascript: `window.external.Notify(args);`

in CS:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    browser.ScriptNotify += browser_ScriptNotify;
}

private void browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    var valueFromBrowser = e.Value;
}
```

For passing data from phone to HTML:

You need to use InvokeScript() method of WebBrowser. There you need to pass name of the function in javascript and input parameters if any.

in javascript: `function doSomething(args) { }`

in CS: `browser.InvokeScript("doSomething", args);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @Abhishek for reply, but this changes my HTML framework, and its not that feasible solution for me. Can you suggest me any other way to achieve.

Comment: What framework are you using? How does it communicate with the outside world? If you use `window.external.Notify()`, it's good to go

Comment: actually this framework is build for SCORM (eLearning) courses.


SCORM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharable_Content_Object_Reference_Model

Comment: You provide the HTML files and the framework as local files already. This means you might manipulate the framework (in as few locations as possible) to notify the native app code whenever this is required.